# What is the TTS engine that here maps uses

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I am developing an app using here maps. I am using voice guidance provided by them for maneuver data.

Packages used

Voice Catalog ,VoiceGuidanceOptions, VoicePackage

For more understanding, Can I know what TTS engine is used behind by here maps ?

Answer (score 0):

Here uses text in form of compiled packages for voice guidance. There is no API in SDK to modify them. 
For Android, Here uses the standard Android engine i.e android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech

And for IOS, AVSpeechSynthesizer from AVFoundation framework.

These are default frameworks which are available on all devices.

Hope this helps!